# Subtextual sound and Visual amplification sound 

Tags: sound-design, examples, film

Hi guys, can any one please give me an examples of Subtextual sound and Visual amplification sound within a film.

Answer (score 1):

Emmanuel,

Can you clarify what exactly you are asking? I say this because it would be useful to have some idea about what specifically you are looking to find out.

Film sound will contain a lot of subtexts in varying degrees. From a basic illiciting of an emotional response from the audience (animal sounds layered into vehicle sounds for example) right through to sounds meaning 2 different things at the same time. For example, I just put in the sound of a ticking Grandfather's Clock into a scene. Firstly because you can see one in the background, this adds sense of realism to the show. Secondly because it's an old sound you don't come across so much these days and as the room we are in is an antique shop then it adds to the sense of the old. Same sound but given 2 meanings.

As for Visual Amplification, it's not a term I've ever come across in relation to sound. Are you talking about [Added Value](http://filmsound.org/chion/Added.htm)?

Ian

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ian.....Basically Visual Amplication sound is one of the 6 Areas of sound within a film, which are found on the David Sonnenschein`s book (The Expressive Power Of Music, Voice And Sound Effects In Cinema), but I needed a clear understandind of how it works within a film..By the way I`m still a student whose in 2nd year studying Sound Design, so I`ll be aksing you lots of questions based on sound...

Cheers

Comment: @Emmanuel Can you give me a page number as it's not listed in the index.